# Repeat something until it succeeds, but at most 3 times

Tags: java

I have needed to program something like this several times since programming Java:

Do something that might fail. If it fails, try it again but at most 3 (or 2 or 5) times.

This approach should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch(BadException e) {
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

But I do not think that it is very expressive. Do you have a better solution?

Something like this would be nice:

```
try (maxTimes = 3) {
    doSomething();
} catch(BadException e) {
    retry;
}
```

Or:

```
try (maxTimes = 3) {
    doSomething();
    if(somethingFailed()) {
        retry;
    }
}
```

But this is not possible with Java. Do you know a language with which it is possible?

Comment: I think that what you're using is the best approach

Comment: By "expressive", do you mean "using built-in syntax"? What you have is already good enough (although I'd move `break` to the `try` block just after the method call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java does not let you invent your own syntax, but you can define your own method to help you express the concept with less code:

```
public static boolean retry(int maxTries, Runnable r) {
    int tries = 0;
    while (tries != maxTries) {
        try {
            r.run();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tries++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can call this method like this:

```
boolean success = retry(5, () -> doSomething());
// Check success to see if the action succeeded
// If you do not care if the action is successful or not,
// ignore the returned value:
retry(5, () -> doSomethingElse());
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/bqUMl7)